# How to deactivate nvidia 9600M GT on a Macbookpro 5,1/5,2/5,3

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, nvidia, macbook

I have a MacbookPro 5,1/5,2/5,3 that comes with two graphic cards, and by default I get the 9600M GT that consumes more battery that the other one. I have no idea how to deactivate it and activate the second one.

More details after the Bruno's reply:

I'm using Ubuntu :

- 11.10 64 bits with kernel 3.0.0-15-generic (Zegnus, MBP 5,1)
- 12.04 64 bits with kernel 3.2-0-24-generic (Megagolgoth, MBP 5,3)

I have installed rEFIt 0.14, and GRUB2 EFI64

I've modified the entry on the file /boot/grub/grub.cfg adding

```
outb 0x750 0
```

even though at the top of the file it says:

```
DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE

It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
```

I save the file, boot, select the entry and then I have a **black screen** and nothing more happens.

I've tried https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting#Selecting_the_graphic_card too, with the same result.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I have the same problem, if I disable 9600 with `outb`, I get black screen.

Comment: @MladenJablanović: I'm on MBP5,3 and having severe trouble with the graphics. Maybe we should share results.

Comment: This helped me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/149921/how-to-add-a-command-permanently-to-grub2

Comment: I need more help. After adding Outb 0x750 0 to grub.cfg. I stuck at black screen at startup. I even cant switch between terminals using alt+F1. What do you suggest My laptop is 5,1 9600M GT with 256 megs of memory.

Answer (score 3):

To disable the Nvidia 9600M GT you have to add the following to the grub menu entry `outb 750x0`, ie:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-12-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux     --class gnu --class os {
    outb 0x750 0
    recordfail
    set gfxpayload=$linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root bc495raf-515r-4r2b-b3de-0ec679a7303a
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-12-generic root=UUID=bc495raf-515r-4r2b-    b3de-0ec679a7303a ro hpet=force
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-12-generic
}
```

---

Additionally for powerdown after resume after suspend:

On resume, the discrete graphics controller will be turned on and active. We need to turn it off and switch back to the integrated GPU.

This can be done with a very simple little program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/io.h>

#define PORT_SWITCH_DISPLAY 0x710
#define PORT_SWITCH_SELECT 0x728
#define PORT_SWITCH_DDC 0x740
#define PORT_DISCRETE_POWER 0x750

static int gmux_switch_to_igd()
{
outb(1, PORT_SWITCH_SELECT);
outb(2, PORT_SWITCH_DISPLAY);
outb(2, PORT_SWITCH_DDC);
return 0;
    }

    static void mbp_gpu_power(int state)
{
    outb(state, PORT_DISCRETE_POWER);
    }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
if (iopl(3) < 0) {
perror ("No IO permissions");
return 1;
}
mbp_gpu_power(0);
gmux_switch_to_igd();
return 0;
}
```

Save that in a file called igd.c. Compile it with `gcc -O2 igd.c -o igd`. This will create an executable called `igd`. Executed with superuser privileges, it will turn off the discrete controller and switch to the integrated controller.

Now we need to execute this on resume. Create a file called `/etc/pm/sleep.d/10igd`

It should contain:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
/path/to/igd
```

Where /path/to is the path to where you put the `igd` executable we created in the previous step.

```
chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/10igd
```

This file will be executed on suspend and resume. Done right, that 10igd script would check to see if this is a suspend/resume/freeze/thaw and only execute when needed. As-is, it executes on all of them. No big deal, it won't hurt to run it during freeze or suspend.

I got everything working on my mbp5,1: Sound, LCD Backlight, Keyboard backlight, Fans running low (since disabling 9600M GT),Apple like short cut (CMD+C to copy),Flash (almost stable)... So just ask if you need more help

Comment: Hi @BrunoPereira, I've updated my question with more details based on your reply. Thank you very much.