# How to add a command permanently to grub2

Tags: grub2, macbook

I have a fairly special setup, using Linux on a MacBook Laptop.

to switch off my secondary graphics card in it I'm required to add these lines to my grub

```
outb 0x728 1
outb 0x710 2
outb 0x740 2
outb 0x750 0
```

I do this by pressing 'e' for my selected grub menu option and adding the lines one by one . then finally booting . But as we know it's not permanent.

I cant really figure out where i need to add it for grub to always append it to my Linux boot options.

It's doesn't seem to belong in  /etc/default/grub
since here i can add stuff to the kernel boot line

Honestly i'm afraid to fiddle to much with grub on my computer since getting it to triple boot Linux/Mac/Windows was a very delicate and timely matter.

Does anyone have any idea of where to add it?

Comment: I think you should read this manual -> https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting

Comment: When you add them after 'e' at grub where are you adding them? Might need to work it into one of the scripts grub reads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add this code to /boot/grub/custom.cfg (creating the file if it doesn't already exist) then it will be executed just before the grub menu is displayed.

I don't know what exactly those outb commands are doing so I have no idea if it is safe to run them at all, or if running them will interfere with display of the grub menu, so do this at your own risk.

Comment: It worked wonders, thnx for the help. an interesting note is that  the commands are not appended to any of the grub menu alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, to prevent an update to `grub` from destroying your `/boot/grub/custom.cfg` I would highly advice you to, at the `GRUB` prompt, hit `e` to edit the default boot menu:

If all is successfull, which usually involves mutating the line, in my case of a **MBP 8 2**:

**A.** Boot USB Drive -

`linux /casper/vmlinuz.efi file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---`

to

`linux /casper/vmlinuz.efi file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper radeon.modeset=0 i915.modeset=1 i915.lvds_use_channel_mode=2 i915.lvds_use_ssc=0 ---`

**B.** Ubuntu should boot, and display a normal graphics screen.

After finishing the installation, repeat 
**A** from above.

**C**
Once booted from the HD, to which you just installed Ubuntu, from the *Live USB* stick,

1. Edit `sudo vi /etc/grub.d/00_header`

   - And insert:

     `outb 0x728 1
     outb 0x710 2
     outb 0x740 2
     outb 0x750 0`

after the line, by searching for `gfx`, which reads: `set gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE}`. An excerpt of the snippet is below:

`set gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE}
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm`

After this procedure `/etc/grub.d/00_header` should look like:

  `set gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE}
  outb 0x728 1
  outb 0x710 2
  outb 0x740 2
  outb 0x750 0
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm`

2. Issue `update-grub`

This way, next time you run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and there happens to be a `grub` upgrade, your install will not shit the bed.

Cheers
rivanov