# Raring on Laptop with two GPUs: black screen

Tags: 13.04, uefi, hybrid-graphics, nomodeset

I bootet my Macbook 8-2 with Kubuntu Rarings

Normal Live CD mode: Only discrete AMD GPU found, everthings fine.

EFI Installer (EFI mode needed to use other GPU): Screen goes black (even on ttys).

So I do the same, but use `nomodeset` on the GRUB line: Splash and Installer GUI show, but "Try Kubuntu" (Live CD mode) gives black screen.

I install Kubuntu, reboot, boot holds: `radeondrmfb` has a problem taking away the framebuffer from the `intel` driver (two GPUs).

So I use `nomodeset` again. Splash, boot runs through to text login, no X: `lightdm` not running. Xorg.log tells me "no displays found".

Any ideas? Basically I just want to use Intel iGPU to save battery.

Answer (score 0):

[ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MacBook_Pro_8,1_/_8,2_/_8,3_%282011_Macbook_Pro%29) knows how to do it without rEFInd ... maybe you have to let go of AMD, but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use EFI mode and Linux at the same time. For some reason the mac books go all wiggly. Use BIOS mode and then enable the intel chip.

[This question worked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73332/how-to-deactivate-nvidia-9600m-gt-on-a-macbookpro-5-1-5-2-5-3) for me last time I tried.